# JQuery функция при клике срабатывает многократно

Tags: jquery

Файл html содержит таблицу:

```
<table>
<tr>
<a class="link" href="account/1" "data-id": "1">
</tr>
<tr>
<a class="link" href="account/2" "data-id": "2">
</tr>
</table>
```

В контроллере:

```
$(".link").on("click", function(event){
let $target = $(event.target),
$parent = $target.closest("tr");
$parent.remove();
console.log("clicked")
})
```

В результаате при клике в консоли функция выполняется столько раз, сколько рядов в таблице. Как сделать, чтобы она выполнялась единожды - только для блока, на который направлен клик?

Comment: "при клике в консоли" - это что значит?

Comment: При клике на ссылку, в консоли... и т.д.

Comment: этого не может быть (. Создайте пример, воспроизводящий наблюдаемое поведение.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".link").on("click", function(){
  var target = $(this).parent();
  target.hide();
  console.log("clicked")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="link" href="#" data-id="1">1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="link" href="#" data-id="2">2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Не совсем понял что у вас там это делает `"data-id": "1"` причем написано неверно